# How to write a method which will take an array of ints in the argument

Tags: java, arrays, methods, task

In my programming task I have to write a method which will take an array of ints in the argument and return a new array filled with only even numbers from the input array. The resulting array cannot have any zeros and is intended to be as large as there are even numbers.
Can I ask for help

```java
public class ArraysToMethod {
   public int max(int [] array) {
      int max = 0;

      for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++ ) {
         if(array[i]>max) {
            max = array[i];
         }
      }
      return max;
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share code which you have tried?

Comment: Thanks for editing

Comment: Umm, I'm a bit confused. Code you shared seems to be doing something else...(finding max element)

Comment: for sure Im wrong with my code, Im looking for some advice

Comment: How to do it correctly ?

Comment: If this is your try to solve the problem can you answer me 2 questions: 1. Why did you choose the return type `int` for that method? 2. Why did you call that method `max`?

Comment: my mistake. I think in return should be new array? Isn't it?? Im still try to find how to write this method

Comment: OP, your post/question says that you need "return a new array" and now is comments you ask if it should be an array? PPL are trying to help u and, help them understand u.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem involves these four tasks:

1. Checking whether a number is not zero and is even. You can easily check whether a number if even or odd and greater than zero with a simple function like this:

```java
private static boolean isEvenAndNotZero(int num) {
    return (num != 0) && (num % 2 == 0);
}
```

2. Counting number of even numbers. You can use utility function created above to count number of even elements like this:

```java
private static int getNumberOfEvenElements(int[] inputArr) {
    return (int) Arrays.stream(inputArr)
            .filter(ArraysToMethod::isEvenAndNotZero)
            .count();
}
```

3. Allocating a result array which doesn't contain zero or even numbers. You just have to consume output of your previous method for your result array size:

```java
int[] resultArr = new int[getNumberOfEvenElements(inputArr)];
```

4. Copying even numbers to result array and returning it. For this you just have to iterate input and result array and copy those values which satisfy the condition described in 1st point.

When you combine all these, your resultant function should look like this:

```java
private static int[] getEvenElementsArray(int[] inputArr) {
    // 1. Count number of Even Elements
    int nEvens = getNumberOfEvenElements(inputArr);
    // 2. Create result array with size = number of even elements
    int[] resultArr = new int[nEvens];

    // 3. Iterate over input array to copy even values
    //    to result array
    int resultIndex = 0;
    for (int j : inputArr) {
        // 4. Check fields which are even and not zero
        if (isEvenAndNotZero(j)) {
            resultArr[resultIndex] = j;
            resultIndex++;
        }
    }
    return resultArr;
}
```

Comment: If inputArr is final, why the second condition?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question? What difference would `inputArr` being final would make to second condition? Do you mean 2nd point in my answer or comment in final listing?

Comment: there is a problem with int nEvens = getNumberOfEvenElements(inputArr); and with isEvenAndNtZero

Comment: its show me that "cannot resolve method"

Comment: Umm, I tested this code in my IDE before posting this answer. By problem do you mean compilation problem ? I'm on Java 8 bdw

Comment: should I put this four tasks to the code??

Comment: @RohanKumar, no, I mean second condition `&& resultIndex < resultArr.length` in `for` loop.

Comment: oh, yeah. You're right. It's redundant. Thanks a lot for noticing! I'll update it

Comment: @starskyhutch, of course! Otherwise, how does compiler know about them?

Comment: @starskyhutch: Yes, I didn't want to give complete answer. You need to combine all the points together. I thought you would figure it out by yourself :-) . But here is the code with which I tried this on https://github.com/r0haaaan/stackoverflow-code/blob/master/java-posts/src/main/java/in/rohaan/ArraysToMethod.java

Comment: @RohanKumar thanks a lot! I will try to read this code slowly and understood what was wrong.